# Merge records into one based on sequence number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data in my SEQUENCE_NUMBER table:

```
NUMBER |BUSINESS_VALUE|TEMP_V|SEQUENCE_NUMBER
123    |10            |10    |1
123    |20            |20    |2
123    |30            |30    |4
234    |40            |50    |1
```

I would like to transform the data as following:

```
NUMBER|VALUE_1|VALUE_2|VALUE_3|VALUE_4|TEMP_1|TEMP_2|TEMP_3|TEMP_4
123   |10     |20     |NULL   |30     |10    |20    |NULL  |30
234   |40     |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |50    |NULL  |NULL  |NULL
```

So based on SEQUENCE_NUMBER I am deciding which column number should be used during inserting to other table.
Do you know how can I perform this kind of a "merge"/"linearising" operation in SQL?

Comment: Google:  `SQL Server pivot`.

Comment: Is `BUSINESS_VALUE` and `TEMP_V` dynamic or static (always 4 values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a known (or maximum) number of values, and don't want to DYNAMIC

The subquery will UNPIVOT your source data

**Example**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select A.[NUMBER]
              ,B.* 
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                        values (concat('Value_',[SEQUENCE_NUMBER]),[BUSINESS_VALUE])
                              ,(concat('Temp_',[SEQUENCE_NUMBER]),[TEMP_V])
                     ) B(Item,Value)
      ) src
 Pivot (max(Value) for Item in ([VALUE_1],[VALUE_2],[VALUE_3],[VALUE_4],[TEMP_1],[TEMP_2],[TEMP_3],[TEMP_4]))pvt
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: @bontade Happy it helped